# How to throw exception in void function?

Tags: php

I have `abc()` which set `$string`. But I want to throw exception if `$string` not set. I don't know how do that. I should use if statement but I don't know what statement I should use. I will gratefull I someone give me tips how I can modify this function that throw exception if not `$string` set.

```
public function abc(string $string): void
{
    $this->string = $string;
    trow new Exception("Message");
}
```

Comment: The function beeing void does not change anything to the throwing of exceptions, also please note that it's throw not trow

Comment: @Lk77 So how can I do that ? Could you show me example ?

Comment: Well simply throw the exception like so : `throw new Exception("Message");`

Comment: @Lk77 but I must add any if which check if `$string` set

Comment: yes of course, but note that your $string parameter will always be set, you can't pass null or nothing to the the funcion for example, because the $string parameter is typed with string type. What you want to do, is to check if the string is empty, you can do a if with : `empty($string)` for example

Comment: @Lk77 I dont' understand how I can check if parametr is set

Comment: You don't really need to check if the parameter is set, because it is, what you can do is check if it's empty. There is no scenario where the abc function is called but the $string parameter is not provided, because it will trigger an exception. However you might want to trigger an exception if the abc function is not called at all, which is a different scenario

Comment: @Lk77 ok So I want to trigger an exception if the abc function is not called at all, how can I do ?

Comment: The best way, would be to put it in the constructor, instead of a method, so there is no way to not provide it. If you want to keep it as a method, you will have to check `$this->string` before using it, i would replace `$this->string` everywhere by a method `$this->getString()`, and throw an exception in that `getString` method if `$this->string` is missing. That way it's the same logic everywhere to throw the exception, and you don't duplicate checks everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by `if $string is not set`.

As pointed out in the comments, if you don't pass *anything* to `abc` it will result in an Exception being thrown:

```
<?php

class Test {
    public function abc(string $string): void {
        $this->string = $string;
        //throw new Exception("Message");
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->abc();
```

So you can't invoke `abc` without providing `$string`. Is that what you want? If it is, then you don't have to do anything.

If you mean by `is set` that the string is not empty (`""`) you can use `strlen` like this:

```
<?php

class Test {
    public function abc(string $string): void {
        if (!strlen($string) {
            throw new Exception("Message");
        }
        
        $this->string = $string;
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->abc("");
```

Don't use [`empty`](https://www.php.net/empty) as it will report `"0"` as being "empty":

```
var_dump(empty("0")); // bool(true)
var_dump(!strlen("0")); // bool(false)
```